# Prove that there is a bijection between permutations written in canonical cycle notation and one line notation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose $\sigma\in S_{n}$ is written in cycle notation, with its fixed points included. We say $\sigma$ is written in *canonical cycle notation* if each cycle is rotated such that its smallest element is last, and the cycles are arranged in ascending order of their last elements.

For example, $(351)(462)(87)(9)$ is in canonical form.

Define the function $f:S_{n}\to S_{n}$ by removal of parentheses, with the image interpreted in one-line notation. Prove that $f$ is bijective.

This is one of those things that *seems* pretty obvious but I'm having trouble formalising it. It's Foata's fundamental transformation, and the only proof I can find of it is his original one, which is in french.

NB. I realise that this is not the typical definition of canonical form.

Comment: A proof with somewhat esoteric notation, also by Foata but in English, can be found in *Combinatorics on Words (Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications; v. 17.)* Chapter 10: "Rearrangements of Words", Lemma 10.2.1.

Comment: Miklos Bona's book *A Walk Through Combinatorics* has a proof with a different convention for the canonical form as Lemma 6.15.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: in the permutation written in one line notation
$$
351462879
$$
you have enough information to restore the parentheses.

Can you see why $1$ must end the first cycle? Then $2$ the next, and so on.

Comment: So would the approach be to define the inverse of $f$? i.e. put a $($ at the far left, $)($ immediately after the $1$, and after each subsequent lowest entry that hasn't already been enclosed, then a $)$ at the end? Is that enough?

Comment: That would be enough for me.I didn't know that notation had a name and a history. I used it here: https://ac.els-cdn.com/0097316580900126/1-s2.0-0097316580900126-main.pdf?_tid=c2f64895-b731-4d0e-ae02-72d5d1f2305f&acdnat=1551915432_f704e65e49c0457a2040f6defa4af750